# Recyclerview button state changing after onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, button, timer, android-recyclerview, pressed

I have a Recyclerview where there is a button onclicklistener in the viewholder constructor:

```
public ViewHolder(View itemView)
{
    super(itemView);
    ...
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
          ...
        }
    }
}
```

Each item also has a countdown, every second the countdown is decremented and a progressbar of the item is updated to display the time left.
The timer is done with a runnable:

```
countdownHandler.postDelayed(countdownRunnable, 1000);
```

which then iterates through all the items, decrements the countdown and notifies the adapter:

```
countdownRunnable = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Iterator<Item> iterator = countdownTasks.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext())
        {    
            item.decrementCountdown();
            adapter.notifyItemChanged(items.indexOf(item)); 
        }
        if (countdownTasks.size() > 0)
            countdownHandler.postDelayed(countdownRunnable, 1000);
    }
}
```

Here is my problem, it also occurs if there is only one item in the list.
I press the button and is in the pressed state, but when the countdown update triggers, the button is no longer pressed. Releasing the button doesn't activate the button as it should. If I remove the countdown, it works properly.

I don't change the button in onBindViewHolder and I am not scrolling since there is only one item. Is this expected bahavior, that all button presses get canceled as soon as notifyItemChanged is called or am I doing something wrong? Does this even work with the onClickListener or do I need an onTouchListener and save the touchdown state in the item and reset it every update?

Thank you!

Edit:
I found out, that if I set

```
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
```

it works without problems. Does anyone know why that is the case and how I can still get animation without the hassle of remembering all the states?

Answer (score 0):

When you call  `adapter.notifyItemChanged(items.indexOf(item));` it rebind view for that position, which is fresh view stored in `ViewHolder` & don't have a pressed state & that's why it loses button state.

You can do it by using `OnTouchListener` and storing states as you mentioned in question.

I am writing as anshwer since i don't have reputation for comment.